# Get Data from DatagridView from to Object Array then populate ComboBox

Tags: c#, arrays, object, datagridview, combobox

I want to get data from datagridview and then populate the combobox with data from an object array which contains a string

```
public class Departmentinfo
{
   public string departmentname;
   .
   .
   .
   .
}

Departmentinfo dep[];

private void getdepartments()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
       college.department[i].departmentname = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    }
}


private void putdepinfo()
{
    comboBox4.DataSource = dep[].departmentname;
}
```

please suggest !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the code working with this,

```
public class Departmentinfo
{
    public string departmentname;

    private void Departmentinfo(string s)
    {
        this.departmentname = s;
    }
}

List<Departmentinfo> DepInfo = new List<Departmentinfo>();

private void getdepartments()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            DepInfo.Add(new Departmentinfo(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value)));
        }
}

private void putdepartments()
{
    foreach (Departmentinfo dep in DepInfo)
    {
        comboBox4.Items.Add(dep.departmentname);
    }
}
```